# How to resolve a KeyError when requesting a node set in Abaqus Scripting

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm attempting to write a python script that writes all U1 values from different parts to text files for further processing.  I have a defined node set that I care about named TERMINUS and whenever  attempt to run the following code I receive: "Key Error: TERMINUS".  This node set has nodes in three parts.

In the input file:

```
*Nset, nset=Terminus, instance="Collagen Full-1"
    1,  136,  271,  406,  544,  946, 1215
*Nset, nset=Terminus, instance="Collagen Half-1"
   1, 151, 301, 454, 901
*Nset, nset=Terminus, instance="Collagen Small-1"
   1,  24,  47,  70,  96, 162, 207
```

and the python script:

```python
# Python script to write displacements for desired nodes into separate
# files. Each file contains the displacements in the x-direction from
# the last increment of every step.

# Import odb commands
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *

# Import serialization commands
import pickle

# Import OS commands
import os

# Open odb file
import fnmatch

for file in os.listdir('.'):
   if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.odb'):
       odb_file = file

odb = openOdb(odb_file)

# Create folder for node displacement output (may not work on Windows)
if not os.path.exists('./node_displacement_T'):
       os.mkdir('./node_displacement_T')

# Create array with all steps and count the number of steps.
step_list = odb.steps.keys()
numSteps = len(step_list)
last_step = odb.steps.keys()[-1]

# Define which nodes to extract displacements from

node_list_CF = odb.rootAssembly.instances['Collagen Full-1'].nodeSets['TERMINUS']
node_list_CH = odb.rootAssembly.instances['Collagen Half-1'].nodeSets['TERMINUS']
node_list_CS = odb.rootAssembly.instances['Collagen Small-1'].nodeSets['TERMINUS']
node_index = ['node_list_CF','node_list_CH','node_list_CS']

# Output displacements for each node

for part in node_index:

   for node_num in part:

       # Clear/create displacements array
       displacements = []

       # Write displacements from the last frame of every step to
       # separate files for each node
       for step in step_list:

           last_frame = odb.steps[step].frames[-1]

           # Add the value to displacement array...changed values from - 1 to -1
           displacements.append(last_frame.fieldOutputs['U'].values[-1].data[0])

           # Wait to write data to file until last step
           if step == last_step:

               file_name = './node_displacement/node_' + str(node_num) + str(part) + '_disp.txt'
               fid = open(file_name, 'wb')

               for index in range(0, len(displacements)):
                   print>>fid, displacements[index]

               print 'Node ', node_num, ' complete'

               fid.close


odb.close
```

I'm expecting more problems after I resolve this...my issue before is that my previous code was not grabbing the correct displacements because the nodes numbers are attached to each part (i.e. there are multiple nodes called node 1).

Any help would be appreciated...I have already assessed odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets.keys()
and ensured that TERMINUS is present as a node set.

Comment: Which line does the `KeyError` occur on? If you identify that, it might help you troubleshoot further. Note that the node sets on the assembly are not the same as the node sets on each instance. You should check the `nodeSets.keys()` on each of the instances as well to inspect if `TERMINUS` is a valid key.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  It says it failed on line 41, but then prints out the line: 

`node_list_CF = odb.rootAssembly.instances['Collagen Full-1'].nodeSets['TERMINUS'] `

I will try and figure out how to check the node sets on each instance, frankly having a lot of trouble understanding the manual.

Comment: @brady , you were totally right, when I used `CFnodes = odb.rootAssembly.instances['Collagen Full-1'].nodeSets.keys()
CHnodes = odb.rootAssembly.instances['Collagen Half-1'].nodeSets.keys()
CSnodes = odb.rootAssembly.instances['Collagen Small-1'].nodeSets.keys()`  to assess the node sets in each instance, Terminus was not a part of them. Do you think I should try to figure out how to make the node set Terminus a part of each instance or just change the way I'm querying to get Terminus?

Comment: I'm guessing your `*Nset` keywords are defined within the `*Assembly`, resulting in them being part of the assembly and not the instance. You might try defining the node sets inside the applicable `*Part` keyword, instead. I believe that will make the node sets available on the instances.

Comment: @brady: Thank you very much, I'll try adjusting the input file and re-running.